# Removing a term from a model in R

Tags: r, regression

Below is a regression model in R with the terms I want to include.

```
fit <- lm(y ~ A + B + C + A:B + A:C + A:B:C)
```

I want the terms A, B, C, AB, AC, and ABC. However the model above is also including BC which I do not want. So, I tried this.

```
fit <- lm(y ~ A + B + C + A:B + A:C + A:B:C - B:C)
```

However, this does not get rid of the BC either. It's still included in the model. How can I remove BC?

Comment: model 1 doesn't include BC

Comment: It does, it includes all possible interactions from A:B:C

Comment: We need a [mcve] please - see my answer for possible source of confusion.

Comment: can you show us `colnames(model.matrix(fit))` for your examples?

Answer (score 2):

We might need more information (I'm posting this as an answer rather than a comment for clarity, can come back and delete it later.)

Looking at a minimal example *where the input variables are numeric*, your statement doesn't seem to be true:

```r
dd <- data.frame(A=1:3, B=1:3, C=1:3)
colnames(model.matrix( ~ A + B + C + A:B + A:C + A:B:C - B:C, dd))
[1] "(Intercept)" "A"           "B"           "C"           "A:B"        
[6] "A:C"         "A:B:C"
```

We have 7 predictor variables, which is what we'd expect if we take the (1 + 3 + 3 + 1) variables expected from a full 3-way interaction and drop 1 2-way interaction term.

Things get more complicated if your input variables are factors:

```r
dd <- data.frame(A=factor(1:3), B=factor(1:3), C=factor(1:3))
colnames(model.matrix( ~ A + B + C + A:B + A:C + A:B:C - B:C, dd))
 [1] "(Intercept)" "A2"          "A3"          "B2"          "B3"         
 [6] "C2"          "C3"          "A2:B2"       "A3:B2"       "A2:B3"      
[11] "A3:B3"       "A2:C2"       "A3:C2"       "A2:C3"       "A3:C3"      
[16] "A1:B2:C2"    "A2:B2:C2"    "A3:B2:C2"    "A1:B3:C2"    "A2:B3:C2"   
[21] "A3:B3:C2"    "A1:B2:C3"    "A2:B2:C3"    "A3:B2:C3"    "A1:B3:C3"   
[26] "A2:B3:C3"    "A3:B3:C3"
```

You can see that the model has 27 predictor variables, which is what you'd expect for the full (3 x 3 x 3) interaction model - i.e. you haven't saved anything by dropping the `B:C` interaction, just reparameterized the same model. (Note, however, that there are no *explicit* `Bx:Cy` interaction terms in the model; they have all been converted to three-way interaction terms instead.) R's formula interface is not quite flexible to deal with this case.

Comment: Yes, they are factors